# Melt Cup together with handle

Tags: modeling

How to seamless connect a handle to a cup?

What i have done:

1. I add a Nurbs-Cylinder and close the bottom. (The cup).
2. I add Bezier-Curve formed like the profile of a handle.
3. I add a Bezier-Circle formed like the intersection of the handle.
4. Set the Bezier-Circle as Bevel Object.
5. Resize the nodes of the Bezier-Curve.
6. Render
   [image]

The Handle touches the cup just a little bit.

How to Seal the handle with the cup?

Comment: Convert them to meshes, join these meshes and join their topology, preferably leaving it as "all quads". You can read more e.g. [in this lesson](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Coffee-Cup-Using-Blender), starting from the part 3 of 8.

Comment: It would help to see the topology of the mesh.  I would to check out Johnson Martin's [topology guides](http://topology-guides.tumblr.com/) for some ideas on how to cut a hole in a mesh, then use [Ctrl]+[E] > *Bridge Edge Loops* to connect the handle to the hole in the cup.

Comment: There is no Mesh. Why do you think it is a mesh?

Comment: you can convert to a [mesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh) with [Alt]+[C].

Comment: @PGmath hitting "W" is faster for "Ctrl+e" when it comes to bridging edge loops.

Comment: @PeterRader "There is no mesh. Why do you think it is a mesh?". There IS a mesh. Everything that you can display is a mesh. Right now you are just generating this mesh with a nurbs surface. Blender is a very bad nurbs editor, but an excellent mesh editor. That's why you need to quit using nurbs to represent your surface. Use subsurface subdivided meshes - e.g. cage meshes to represent your surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the bridge function of the loop tools add-on if you have it enabled. You can find it under user  preferences> add-ons if you don't. In the attached gif I used a curve for the handle of my cup, and a cylinder for the cup itself. Press  <kbd>Alt+C</kbd>  to convert the curve object to a mesh object, then  <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>RMB</kbd> to select both objects. Then press  <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> to join your meshes. Now you can delete the unnecessary faces, and bridge the appropriate edges. To do so, use  <kbd>Alt+RMB</kbd>  to select your first edge loop, then <kbd>Shift+Alt+RMB</kbd> to select your second edge loop, and click bridge under the loop tools options.[image]

Comment: And if i do not like to work on Meshes?

Comment: @PeterRader Blender's Curve surfaces editing capabilities will not be satisfactory for what you want. Blender is at it's heart a Polygon modelling tool.